# Need to do reasoning over owl

Tags: prolog, owl, swi-prolog

I have an owl  file over which i need to do sole reasoning.
I opted for prolog and have problems in finding resources to write my algorithme in prolog.
Please help

Comment: what is the question now? And I can't believe that you can't find any SWI Prolog API for OWL ... there is at least one API which is very well known ...

Comment: http://www.semanticweb.gr/thea/index.html ?